# How to send Images one Activity to another Activity using Intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I've created one `Listview` and when I click on list view, I want to send that row image details at Detail view Activity (another activity).

For this I tried below code but I'm getting below Exception

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

### FirstActivity:-

```
 // Listen for ListView Item Click

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageId",(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getImageId()));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
             }
        });
    }
```

### SecondActivity:-

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);


        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the results of imageView
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("imageId");
        srcimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);
        srcimage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

Comment: your first activity code i completely wrong. You should use onListItemClickListener for list item click event instead of onCLickListener

Comment: that is not a problem when i send textview data instead of image that's goind well to another activity and setOnClickListener i wrote in Listview adapterClass

Comment: (worldpopulationlist.get(position).getImageId()) might be an integer value.

Comment: yes yes ur right that's storing integer array values then how can solve this

Comment: you are getting data properly because you are passing position and that will work but this is not a proper way of doing this

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12757387/2826147)

Comment: refer this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: hello i have already try those answers and i have stored my darwable images in integer array

Comment: You are passing Integer and getting it in a Bitmap variable. Thats wrong. You need to convert drawable to Bitmap first.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.Because you pass a integer value in your FirstActivity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int yourImageId =  i.getIntExtra("imageId"); <----

    }
```

Comment: i.getIntExtra("imageId"); showing errorrs this line

Comment: yea beacuse you must asign to some variable or what you want .. edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do so:

1. get the bytes from bitmap of image and post it as byte array in intent receive it and reconvert it in bitmap but activity transition becomes slow in this case;
2. store image somewhere retrieve it in other activity then delete it then.